# Pasting together all combinations of a column from one data.frame with all combinations of a column of another data.frame based on a condition

Tags: r, apply, nested-loops

I am in need of some wisdom!

I have two data frames, like:

```
test1 <- data.frame( let = replicate( 100, paste(sample(LETTERS[1:12] , 3 ) , collapse ="")  ) , num  = sample( 1:500 , 100 , replace = FALSE ))
test2 <- data.frame( let = replicate( 100, paste(sample(LETTERS[13:26] , 4 ) , collapse ="")  ) , num  = sample( 1:500 , 100 , replace = FALSE ))

head( test1 )
#   let num
# 1 KDA 430
# 2 IHB  41
# 3 GAB 473
# 4 HKJ 335
# 5 LCK 261
# 6 EIK 500

head( test2 )
#   let num
# 1 ZUYW 153
# 2 PRNW 263
# 3 OTQS 355
# 4 NYRW  87
# 5 ZYST 365
# 6 TXRN 287
```

Now, I want to paste all combinations of strings from test1 (i.e. test1$let) with all combinations of strings from test2, but only when difference test1$num and test2$num is <= 100.

One way to do this is:

```
test.merg <- NULL
i <- 1; j <- 1
for(i in 1:dim(test1)[1] ) {
  for( j in 1:dim(test2)[1]  ) { 
    if( abs( test1[i,]$num - test2[j,]$num ) <= 100  ){
      test.merg <- c(test.merg ,paste( test1[i,]$let , test2[j,]$let , sep="."   ) )
      }
    j <- j+ 1
    }
  i <- i+ 1
}
head(test.merg)
#[1] "KDA.OTQS" "KDA.ZYST" "KDA.TVRX" "KDA.VYRQ" "KDA.XRQS" "KDA.WSUR"
```

This works fine, but of course my actual dataset is different and huge, and it takes a long time to do this. I am sure that there must be a more efficient way of doing this. Tried using the apply family functions, but the only way I could think of using them is:

```
test1.1 <- paste( test1$let , test1$num ,sep = "_")
test2.1 <- paste( test2$let , test2$num ,sep = "_")

test.merg.1 <- unlist(lapply( test1.1 , FUN = function(x) {lapply( 
  test2.1 , FUN = function(y) {
    if( abs( as.numeric( str_split_fixed( x , "_" , 2 )[,2] )  - as.numeric( str_split_fixed( y , "_" , 2 )[,2]) ) <= 100){ 
      paste( str_split_fixed(x , "_" , 2 )[,1] , str_split_fixed(y , "_" , 2 )[,1], sep = ".")
  }
})
})
)

head(test.merg.1)
# [1] "KDA.OTQS" "KDA.ZYST" "KDA.TVRX" "KDA.VYRQ" "KDA.XRQS" "KDA.WSUR"
```

This already reduces the time taken by quite a lot, to almost 1/4th , but it would be great if it can be made more efficient. Not to mention, if there is a completely different and better way of doing this then it will be fantastic.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `library(data.table); setDT(test2)[, num1 := num + 100];setDT(test1)[test2, on = .(num <= num1), allow.cartesian = TRUE][, , .(let, i.let)]`

Comment: how big is your actual dataset ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: data comes from gene sequences, and for a gene there will be more than 100,000 combinations of gene fragments pasted to all combination of another 100,000 gene fragments.

Comment: Alright, forget my solution right away then :). What is your fraction of `abs(test1$num-test2$num)  <= 100` approximately ? if it's extremely low we could think of an algorithm but the size of your object is `10.000.000.000` * `this proportion` * `size of an 8 character string`, so you might need another approach to your general problem...

Comment: A solution might be to cut both vectors in `n` chunks, say `10`, and apply any of the 2 solutions (they're the same thing), thus you would expand a data set that would be `n^2` times smaller, `100` times with my suggestion, so you'd create first a table 100 million rows, filter it for your criteria, save the filtered object or save it somewhere, and go on with the next chunk combination

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestions and the answers. Once I am not stuck in the lab, I will try these and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `outer` statements work here

```
outer(test1$let, test2$let, "paste", sep=".")[abs(outer(test1$num, test2$num, "-")) <= 100]

# [1] "DEF.VOXZ" "FHJ.VOXZ" "CHB.VOXZ" "JBH.VOXZ" etc
```

Reproducible data

```
set.seed(1)
test1 <- data.frame( let = replicate( 100, paste(sample(LETTERS[1:12] , 3 ) , collapse ="")  ) , num  = sample( 1:500 , 100 , replace = FALSE ))
test2 <- data.frame( let = replicate( 100, paste(sample(LETTERS[13:26] , 4 ) , collapse ="")  ) , num  = sample( 1:500 , 100 , replace = FALSE ))
```

Benchmark

```
OP <- function() {
test.merg <- NULL
i <- 1; j <- 1
for(i in 1:dim(test1)[1] ) {
  for( j in 1:dim(test2)[1]  ) { 
    if( abs( test1[i,]$num - test2[j,]$num ) <= 100  ){
      test.merg <- c(test.merg ,paste( test1[i,]$let , test2[j,]$let , sep="."   ) )
      }
    j <- j+ 1
    }
  i <- i+ 1
}
head(test.merg)
}

myfun <- function() {
outer(test1$let, test2$let, "paste", sep=".")[abs(outer(test1$num, test2$num, "-")) <= 100]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(), myfun(), times=10L)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
    OP() 4877.0017 4928.447303 5014.859718 5017.653519 5056.110679 5236.55990    10
 myfun()    5.8398    5.951762    8.501438    6.709145    7.842536   25.16273    10
```

It's almost 500x faster

Comment: Thank you! I was playing with "outer" but it just didn't occur to me to use a combination of two outers like two lapply'es. This was also the fastest among the four ways I tested.

Comment: I'm still learning how to use `outer` as often as possible as well

Comment: great! so for `outer( X , Y , FUN, ... )` FUN can be a user defined function?

Answer (score 1):

something like this ?

Note: if your dataset is really "huge" as you say, your computer will not like that, but if you want every possible combination I don't see any other way.

```
res <- merge(test1 %>% rename_all(paste0,1),
             test2 %>% rename_all(paste0,2)) %>%
  filter(abs(num1-num2) <= 100) %>%
  mutate(str = paste(let1,let2,sep="_"))
#    let1 num1 let2 num2      str
# 1  DJE   82 VNQU  181 DJE_VNQU
# 2  JLE  238 VNQU  181 JLE_VNQU
# 3  EGI  220 VNQU  181 EGI_VNQU
# 4  KED  130 VNQU  181 KED_VNQU
# 5  CJF   81 VNQU  181 CJF_VNQU
# 6  KCH  235 VNQU  181 KCH_VNQU
# ...

head(res$str)
#[1] "DJE_VNQU" "JLE_VNQU" "EGI_VNQU" "KED_VNQU" "CJF_VNQU" "KCH_VNQU"
```

Comment: How does this work when there is no "by" argument for "merge" to compare and use?

Comment: It then returns all possible combinations, try `merge(1:3,1:2)`

Comment: Great, thank you! This works and always love a method using dplyr. But "outer" was faster so I have accepted that as the answer. Also, didn't know that "merge" can work this way. +1 for that. Now have to up-implement this to my actual problem.

Comment: good luck :). can you come back and tell us if/how you managed to make it cork on this big amount of data ?